# MATLAB: Applying multiple values to each (x,y) coordinate point in a 2D Cartesian coordinate system

Tags: matlab, vector, cartesian-coordinates

I have a `(5x1)` vector `V = (V1, V2, V3, V4, V5)` and would like to assign these five values to each grid point in an (x,y) coordinate system. So for instance `(x,y) = (1,1)` may have values of `V = (1, 0.432, -5, 2, 67)` and `(x,y) = (2,3)` may have values of `V = (-43, 3.53, 0.423, -4, -0.432)` assigned to it. Is there a good data structure that will be able to do this in MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Same number of values everywhere

If you want to assign the same number of values to each grid point, it is best to create a 5xXxY matrix, for example

```
xy_vals = rand([5 nx ny]);
```

where you can access the values at point (xx,yy) via

```
test_vals = xy_vals(:,xx,yy);
```

#### Flexible number of values at each grid point

If you want to be flexible about the number of values per grid point, I suggest a cell-array of arrays. For example:

```
xy_cell = cell([nx ny]);
for ix = 1:nx
    for iy = 1:ny
        xy_cell{ix,iy} = randi([1 randi(10)]);
    end
end
```

Now, access the vaues at point (xx,yy) via

```
test_vals = xy_cell{xx,yy};
```

Comment: Thank you very much Richard.